# How do you make an image allow text to wrap around it in HTML?

Tags: html, css, image

I am starting my first site and it is posted online here: [Link to my site](http://studentweb.ewu.edu/jhazel/)

However, as you can see the UL (list) or any other text is on a new line instead of side by side with the image.  I figured it should be on the same line since it is in the same  tag but it is not.

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `float` CSS property. This is actually the original purpose of the `float` property.

e.g.:

```
img#yourImage {
    float: left;
}
```

Don't forget to use the `clear` property on an element after the element to which you applied the `float`. Alternatively, you can use `clear` on a "virtual" element created with `:after`.

*Update*: [This site](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/float.php) actually provides a good explanation and example.

Answer (score 0):

add this css to `ul.favourites`

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

I personally prefer this over `float:left`. I hope this helps!